# "Endianness" issue when building application with pjsip for android version 2.4

Tags: android, pjsip

We use pjsip for our project and everything worked ok in version 2.2 until we tried to update pjsip version up to 2.4. Now I cannot build the project due to the following error:

> [INFO]from pjsip-static-for-android-2.4.0/headers/pjmedia/types.h:28,
>
> [INFO]from
>   pjsip-static-for-android-2.4.0/headers/pjmedia/alaw_ulaw.h:23,
>
> [INFO]from pjsip-static-for-android-2.4.0/headers/pjmedia.h:27,
>
> [INFO] pjsip-static-for-android-2.4.0/headers/pj/config.h:248:6:
>   error: #error Endianness must be declared for this processor

Search in google about the "endianness" says that it is an IOS related matter, but I configure for android only, and now I have no idea what does it mean and why it asks me to declare it.
I read pjsip configuration and pjsip FAQ, but no answer for the issue.

Pj/config_site.h has the following contents as explained in documentation

```
#define PJ_CONFIG_ANDROID 1
#include <pj/config_site_sample.h>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: `I have no idea what does it mean ` ? A little googling would leanrn you that in minutes.

Comment: `Endianness must be declared for this processor` Well that's more a .h header include file issue. Aparently a define or declaration is missing. What else. Maybe there is forgotton to include a .h file?